# How to use a bash variable for the @filepath in a curl command

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, curl

I am trying to write a bash script to run a series of curl commands. The command I am trying to run is this:

```
curl -XPUT $URL'/test/' -d @$DATA_DIR/index-settings.json
```

This is my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

DATA_DIR="/usr/local/es"
URL="http://localhost:9200"

curl -XPUT $URL'/test/' -d @$DATA_DIR/index-settings.json
```

I have confirmed that the command works if I run it manually like so:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/' -d @/usr/local/es/index-settings.json
```

The issue is from the $DATA_DIR. When I run the bash script with the $DATA_DIR variable, I get this error:

```
Warning: Couldn't read data from file 
Warning: "/usr/local/es/index-settings.json", this makes 
Warning: an empty POST.
```

Is it possible to use a variable within a curl command that uses -d @ arguments?

Comment: The warning text mentioned the right path, didn't it? So `curl` got it, the variable was expanded properly. Seemingly, because maybe the variable and/or the command in the script contains unprintable characters. Check the script with `xxd -g 1 yourscript`; Is there any byte that begins with `0` and is not `0a`? Is there `0d` maybe? // Do you run the script as another user? Is `/usr/local/es/index-settings.json` readable for the user running the script?

Comment: Running `set -x` before that section of the script might also point out what's happening -- it'll print the commands (or their equivalent) as it executes them, with things like non-printing characters in visible form. BTW, it's generally a good idea to put double-quotes around variable references (and strings that include them), as in `curl -XPUT "$URL/test/" -d "@$DATA_DIR/index-settings.json"`

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks that did the trick! There was a byte that began with 0.

Comment: You should `/usr/local/es/index-settings.json` and ensure it is not empty. Also, you should use double quotes around variables, like `curl -XPUT "$URL/test/" ...`. Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.